# Improving Breadth First Search that finds highest degree of separation in graph

Tags: python, search, optimization

The input graph: I have a dictionary that represents a directed graph where the key is a node and the values are the nodes it is pointing to.

The input heroes: A set of all the nodes

This method is used to find the largest degree of separation between all combinations of nodes.

```
def largestDegreeOfSeparation(graph, heroes):
    q = deque()
    currentHighestDoS = 0
    DoS = 0
    for hero in heroes:
        path = (hero,)
        q.append(path)
        visited = set([hero])
        while q:
            path = q.popleft()
            last_node = path[-1]
            for node in graph[last_node]:
                if node not in visited:
                    visited.add(node)
                    q.append(path + (node,))
        DoS = len(path) - 1
        if DoS > currentHighestDoS:
            currentHighestDoS = DoS
            currentHero = path[0]
            currentHerosDestination = last_node
            print str(currentHero) + '\t' + str(path) + '\t' + str(currentHighestDoS)
```

This program finds a degree of separation of 4, and then 5, and then it just keeps running, I think because its taking too long. Is there a way to make this method run faster?

Comment: I can not become so slow at 6. Look for the errors.

Comment: That's the thing, there are no errors, it just keeps running I have to ctrl + c to stop it.

Comment: Oh. Okay. What is the degree of separation? The graph's diameter?

Comment: its the distance from one node to another. So if node1 has to go to node2, then node3, the degree of separation is 2.

Comment: Do you mean the shortest distance? Do you know what is the graph diameter? Do you know about Bellman–Ford or Floyd–Warshall algorithms?

Comment: Yeah it is the shortest distance because it is a breadth first search. I know about the floyd algorithm but my graph is not weighted.

Comment: Dude, you must defenitely learn some computer science before programming. You graph is weighted, every edge has the same weight, because the weight of the path is the number of edges in it. And if you are programming python, just use the Floyd–Warshall algorithm. Nobody will understand the long ugly code, it isn't C, use something  concise.

Comment: So you are actually looking for the highest degree of separation instaed of the longest path?

Comment: Yeah that is what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `numpy` (np) array with the position of each hero, stored in the same order as another array containing the heros' objects. Suppose you have the hero coordinates:

```
 pos_heros   = np.array( [hero.coordinates for hero in heros], dtype='float64' )
 array_heros = np.array( [hero for hero in heros], dtype = object )
```

Then you compute the distance matrix:

```
 dist  = np.subtract.outer( pos_heros[:,0], pos_heros[:,0] )**2
 dist += np.subtract.outer( pos_heros[:,1], pos_heros[:,1] )**2
 dist += np.subtract.outer( pos_heros[:,2], pos_heros[:,2] )**2
```

Now you will find each of the closest heros by getting the indexes that sort the distance matrix:

```
 a = np.argsort( dist, axis=1 )
```

You can use `np.take` to efficiently obtain the sorted pos_heros matrix:

```
 matrix_heros = np.take( array_heros, a )
```

Each line in the matrix_heros will represent a hero and the first column will be the first closest hero, the second column the second and so forth...

For example, to get the first and second heros closest to a hero at column 10:

```
 matrix_heros[9,0]  # 9--> hero    0-->  first closest hero
 matrix_heros[9,1]  # 9--> hero    1--> second closest hero
```

To find what you want, which is the most distant heros:

```
 ans = matrix_heros[:,-1]
```

The `ans` will contain the most distant heros in the same order that you created `array_heros`.